# Obtener un array con los proximos valores de otro

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy intentando crear un array en pandas con los siguientes valores de otro array pero me aparece un arror de "list assigment index out of range"
A alguien se le ocurre otra manera de poder conseguirlo. Gracias

```
x1=[]
for i in range(4):
    x1[i]= df['Total'][i]
```

Un saludo

Comment: `x1` no tiene elemento `[i]`. O bien creas de antemano en `x1` una serie de elementos (cuyo valor no importa), por ejemplo haciendo `x1 = [0]*len(df)`, entes del bucle o bien vas añadiendo elementos a medida que los creas con `x1.append(df['Total'][i])` dentro del bucle. Depende de si necesitas o no acceder a los elementos de `x1` por su índice para asignarlos.

Comment: Por el lado positivo, ha sido capaz de identificar el problema y plantearlo en un mínimo de código. +1

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que usar el metodo append para x1

```
x1.append(df['Total'][i])
```

Saludos